# Is $\mathbb{C}^{2}$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$ over Rational numbers

Tags: logic, complex-numbers, vector-spaces, axiom-of-choice, vector-space-isomorphism

We can say that $\mathbb{C}^{2}$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$ when both are considered as Vector spaces over the field of Complex numbers or Real numbers. But is $\mathbb{C}^{2}$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$ when both are considered as Vector Spaces over Field of Rational numbers?

Two Finite dimensional Vector spaces over same field are isomorphic iff they are of same dimension. But here $\mathbb{C}^{2}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ are not Finite dimensional over rational numbers. So how can we tackle this problem? Is there any general methodology to establish such isomorphisms in Non finite dimensional case?

Through the comments I got to know Two vector spaces over the same field are isomorphic if and only if their bases have the same cardinality and this is true even in non finite dimensional case. But this requires finding a basis for the above two vector spaces and comparing their cardinalities, this further uses Axiom of choice. Is there a way to avoid this? (because isn't it difficult to find basis for Non finite dimensional vector spaces?) Is there a way to just establish isomorphism between the vector spaces and show they are isomorphic?

Comment: It sounds to me like an Axiom of Choice thing, but I've underestimated the power of non-Choice before.

Comment: Hint: if $\Bbb R$ has dimension $\kappa$ over $\Bbb Q$, what is the dimension of $\Bbb C^n$ over $\Bbb Q$?

Comment: Two vector spaces over the same field are isomorphic if and only if their bases have the  same cardinality (whether finite or infinite).

Comment: But how can we find bases for these vector spaces?

Comment: Do you accept the Axiom of Choice? If you do, google "Hamel basis".

Comment: @MoisheKohan Okay. But without referring to it is there a way to solve the original problem?

Comment: You should edit your question to reflect what do you actually want to know.

Answer (score 0):

It is both simple and difficult to answer your new question. If you believe that in any vector space over a field there exists a basis (finite or infinite), then for the case of a finite or countable field the answer is.

Two infinite-dimensional vector spaces are isomorphic if and only if these spaces have the same cardinality. (Note not the bases, but the spaces.)

Comment: How this can be the case? For instance, infinite-dimensional split-complex numbers ($i_n^2=1$) are not isomorphic to infinite-dimensional tessarines ($i_{2n}^2=-1, i_{2n+1}^2=1$) and not isomorphic to infinite-dimensional Grassmann numbers.

Comment: However, as vector spaces over $\mathbb{Q}$ they are all pairwise isomorphic.

Comment: How they can be isomorphic if split-complex numbers and tessarines are commutative and Grassmann numbers are not?

Comment: @Anixx Because you're considering an algebraic structure (multiplication) which is not part of a vector space. As vector spaces (when the only available multiplication is multiplication by rational numbers) they are isomorphic.

Comment: @Arthur the properties of moduluses are also different

Comment: @Anixx That's still not relevant to vector spaces. Those don't appear until you start to talk about _normed_ vector spaces.